# Unable to verify the ID Token: jwt.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, identity, gitkit

I am trying to verify Google ID Token on Node.js server.

I am getting this error:

```
Unable to verify the ID Token: jwt.split is not a function
```

Here is the link of code that I am following from Google's official documentation:

[Google Identity Toolkit Node](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-node/blob/master/example-app.js)

Comment: Check idToken from client side is  undefined / null or not

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install a jwt framework like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt) or [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-32).
I believe that you need the first link for the server and possible the second link for the website (more info on the website [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/required-endpoints#sign-in_success_url)).

Comment: I have installed google-oauth-jwt and jwt, both but still the error persists.

Comment: @Master, Are you following this quick start? https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_configure_the_quick-start_app

Comment: Yea, I am following it. Right now error is changed to :Key must be a buffer?

Comment: Did you ever find the fix? I am having the same error. If any luck please post an answer

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, locally it worked like a charm, but inside AWS lambda, it caused the same error reported, so I've endup using this URL and Axios(you can use any HTTP client) to check the token validity and domain of the user:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={id_token}

This is the idea:

```
//googleTokenValidatorService
const ENV = require('../config.json');
const AXIOS = require('axios');
function getToken(token) {
  return AXIOS.get(ENV.GOOGLE_VALIDATION_URL + token)
}

function validate(token){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    getToken(token)
      .then(
        (response) => {
          if(isTokenOk(response.data)){
            resolve(response.data)
          }else{
            reject({status:401, message:"You do not have permission to access this resource."})
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("--- status  " + error.response.status + " with token")
          console.log(token)
          reject({status:401, message:"Invalid google token."}) 
        }
      )
  })
}

const acceptableHds = new Set(
  ['validDomain1.com', 'validDomain2.com']
);

const acceptableClientIDs = new Set(
  [ENV.CLIENT_ID_WEB,ENV.CLIENT_ID_IOS, ENV.CLIENT_ID_ANDROID]
)

function isTokenOk(payload){
  return payload &&
    new Date(payload.exp * 1000) > new Date() &&
    acceptableClientIDs.has(payload.aud) &&
    acceptableHds.has(payload.hd)
}

module.exports = { 
  validate
}
```

And then used it to validate before executing some action:

```
    //some other file
return googleUserValidator.validate(request.headers.token)
.then(productService.getProductDetails.bind({id:request.pathParams.id}))
                    .then(OK)
                    .catch(SERVER_ERROR);
```

It was enough for me, hope it helps someone.